# flutter mobile app microsoft authentication integration

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am struggling with getting my flutter mobile app to authenticate using Microsoft authentication via firebase
this is the error I receive :

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

I followed these methods to remedy the problem but I still get the same error

methods I have followed:
*installed and configures flutterfire and connected to my firebase project using the cli
*upgraded my flutter
*initialized it in main

````
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart'
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

///inside my class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget>

 Future<void> performLogin(String provider, List<String> scopes,
      Map<String, String> parameters) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(provider, scopes, parameters);
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      debugPrint("${error.code}: ${error.message}");
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');```
````

yet still I get the same error. could someone please advice me on what to do

Comment: Which firebase_core version are u using?

Comment: firebase_core: ^1.4.0+1